# How to query facebook friends by city in FQL

Tags: facebook, api

Since in FQL, current_location has city
How can I query friends by city ?

e.g., 
select uid,name,pic_small,current_location from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me()) and current_location.city='Sunnyvale'

(Above FQL doesn't work)

Anyone here knows the correct way to do so ?

Cheers

Comment: you can't ...you have to loops over your data

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT current_location, name FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) and "New York" in current_location
```

You might have to create a variable to get it filtered by city.